# Understanding the "build break" rationale for Google's C++ Style Guide's guideline for #include order

Tags: c++, c, header-files

Here is a section on #include's from [Google's C++ style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Names_and_Order_of_Includes):

> In dir/foo.cc or dir/foo_test.cc, whose main purpose is to implement
>   or test the stuff in dir2/foo2.h, order your includes as follows:
>
> ```
> dir2/foo2.h.
> A blank line
> C system files.
> C++ system files.
> A blank line
> Other libraries' .h files.
> Your project's .h files.
> ```
>
> Note that any adjacent blank lines should be collapsed.
>
> With the preferred ordering, if dir2/foo2.h omits any necessary
>   includes, the build of dir/foo.cc or dir/foo_test.cc will break. Thus,
>   this rule ensures that build breaks show up first for the people
>   working on these files, not for innocent people in other packages.

I don't understand the last line:

> Thus, this rule ensures that build breaks show up first for the people
>   working on these files, not for innocent people in other packages.

Can someone explain how putting `dir2/foo2.h` first results in a "good" build break, and how putting `dir2/foo2.h` last results in a "bad" build break?

Comment: I think they just mean that the people working on it could have an include already included so even through it isn't in the object files include, it works for them.. but might break for you when you include just the header for that module... and by structuring it this way it will break for the maintainer because they include dir2/foo2.h first

Comment: This is actually hiding missing includes in your headers, so it doesn't seem like a great idea.

Comment: Accidentally relying on a declaration that appears in another .h file is a very common mistake.  By putting it first you can't not notice.  Standard C++ has this problem, iostream is pretty notorious.

Comment: If your header forgets to include relevant headers, your testing routines are crap. Rather than coming up with obscure coding style rules, improve the way you unit test code. It is industry de facto standard that includes go into the _header_ file and nowhere else, so that the user of the code can easily get an overview of all code dependencies. They should not have to go and dig through the `*.c*` files - they might not even have access to them! Use industry de facto standard coding with good unit testing, instead of Google-mumbo-jumbo standard with bad unit testing.

Comment: @Lundin: "It is industry de facto standard that includes go into the header file and nowhere else" whaat? That is definitely not the case, unless you want crazy compilation times and incremental builds, that rebuild your whole application.

Comment: @Jaa-c Somewhere in the early 90s, compilers and linkers got the ability to tell if source code had been modified or not - if not, it linked the previously built object file. Welcome to 1990s tool chains.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In `dir2.h`, you forget to include `X.h`. Then in current file you include:

```
X.h
dir2.h
```

This will compile fine. Then someone else includes `dir2.h` somewhere else and they end up with compilation error originating from `dir2.h`, even if they never changed anything in that file...

If you have the correct order, you should get the error first time you include `dir2.h`.

Answer (score 4):

A "good" build break is when it breaks for the guy making the breaking changes. Because that guy can repair it. If that guy does *not* notice those breaking changes because the include files are sorted so it does compile for him by plain chance, then it will be released.

A "bad" build break is when the released version breaks the build of the users of that code.